# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I got an run time exception in my program while I am reading a file through a Scanner.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found     
   at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)    
   at Day1.ReadFile.read(ReadFile.java:49)  
   at Day1.ParseTree.main(ParseTree.java:17)
```

My code is:

```
while((str=sc.nextLine())!=null){
    i=0;
    if(str.equals("Locations"))
    {
        size=4;
        t=3;
        str=sc.nextLine();
        str=sc.nextLine();
    }
    if(str.equals("Professions"))
    {
        size=3;
        t=2;
        str=sc.nextLine();
        str=sc.nextLine();
    }
    if(str.equals("Individuals"))
    {
        size=4;
        t=4;
        str=sc.nextLine();
        str=sc.nextLine();
    }

int j=0;
String loc[]=new String[size];
while(j<size){
    beg=0;
    end=str.indexOf(',');
    if(end!=-1){
        tmp=str.substring(beg, end);
        beg=end+2;
    }
    if(end==-1)
    {
        tmp=str.substring(beg);
    }
    if(beg<str.length())
        str=str.substring(beg);
    loc[i]=tmp;
    i++;

    if(i==size ){
        if(t==3)
        {
            location.add(loc);
        }
        if(t==2)
        {
            profession.add(loc);
        }
        if(t==4)
        {
            individual.add(loc);
        }
        i=0;
    }
    j++;
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When posting code you should take care to format it for readability... i.e. remove unnecessary blank lines, indent properly.  Also format your stacktrace as code to make it readable.  I fixed the formatting for you.

Comment: Also, you left out the most important piece, which is how `sc` was declared and opened.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

with `Scanner` you need to check if there is a next line with `hasNextLine()`

so the loop becomes

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    str=sc.nextLine();
    //...
}
```

it's readers that return null on `EOF`

ofcourse in this piece of code this is dependent on whether the input is properly formatted

Answer (score 23):

I also encounter with that problem.
In my case the problem was that I closed the Scanner inside one of the funcs..

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean exit = new Boolean(false);
        while(!exit) {
            String choose = menu.nextLine();
            Part1 t=new Part1()
            t.start();
            System.out.println("Noooooo Come back!!!"+choose);
        }
        menu.close();
    }
}

public class Part1 extends Thread 
{
    public void run()
    { 
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String st = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("bllaaaaaaa\n" + st);
        s.close();
    }
}
```

The code above made the same exeption, the solution was to close the scanner only once at the main.

Comment: Thanks for that buddy, stuck on this tiny mistake

Comment: I have the similar problem. I want to know why it wont work if I close the scanner and re-initialise it again when I read next line. They should both be different instances of scanner right? Why would closing one instance of scanner affect the other one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555283/why-is-not-possible-to-reopen-a-closed-standard-stream

Comment: @KaushikEvani: if you use two separate Scanner objects, after the first scanner is closed, System.in will be closed as well and cannot be opened again. Therefore, when the nextLine() method is called on your second scanner afterwards, it will lead to the NoSuchElementException because System.in is already closed.
You have to make sure that only one Scanner instance is used, so System.in is only closed when it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 18):

You're calling `nextLine()` and it's throwing an exception when there's no line, exactly as the javadoc describes. It will never return `null`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 8):

For whatever reason, the Scanner class also issues this same exception if it encounters special characters it cannot read. Beyond using the `hasNextLine()` method before each call to `nextLine()`, make sure the correct encoding is passed to the `Scanner` constructor, e.g.:

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 8):

Your real problem is that you are calling "sc.nextLine()" **MORE  TIMES** than the number of lines.

For example, if you have only **TEN** input lines, then you can **ONLY** call "sc.nextLine()" **TEN** times.

Every time you call "sc.nextLine()", one input line will be consumed. If you call "sc.nextLine()" **MORE  TIMES** than the number of lines, **you will have an exception called**

```
      "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found".
```

If you have to call "sc.nextLine()" ***n*** times, then you have to have **at least *n*** lines.

Try to change your code to match the number of times you call "sc.nextLine()" with the number of lines, and I guarantee that your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use top comment but also pay attention to **nextLine()**. To eliminate this error only call

```
sc.nextLine()
```

Once from inside your while loop

```
 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {sc.nextLine()...}
```

You are using **while** to look ahead only **1** line. Then using **sc.nextLine()** to read **2** lines ahead of the single line you asked the while loop to look ahead.

Also change the multiple **IF** statements to **IF, ELSE** to avoid reading more than one line also.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, my structure was:
1 - System
2 - Registration <-> 3 - validate

I was closing Scanner on each of the 3 steps. I started to close the Scanner only in system and it solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).