# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, file, exception, file-io, java.util.scanner

#### Information :

when I execute my program, a simple file reader, I get an exception.

I have my file saved next to my .java files.

#### Output :

> run:
>   name : Koen
>   score : 44
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>   name : Kevin
>   score : 55
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
>     at tetris.FileIO.loadHighscores(FileIO.java:41)
>     at tetris.FileIO.getLineScores(FileIO.java:28)
>     at tetris.FileIO.main(FileIO.java:62)
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

#### Code:

```
package tetris;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileIO   {
    private File file;
    private Scanner filescScanner, lineScanner;
    private Writer fileWriter, lineWriter;
    private String[][] data;

    public FileIO () {
        String[][] data = new String[100][1];
    }
    public String[][] getLineScores(){
        return this.loadHighscores(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("LineHighscores.txt"));
    }
    public String[][] getTimeScores(){
        return this.loadHighscores(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("TimeHighscores.txt"));
    }

    public String[][] loadHighscores( InputStream resourceStream){

        int x=0;
        String test = "";

        filescScanner = new Scanner(resourceStream);

        while((test=filescScanner.nextLine())!=null) {

            lineScanner = new Scanner(test);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter("-/-");
            System.out.println("name : "+lineScanner.next());
            System.out.println("score : " +lineScanner.next());

            x++;
        }
        lineScanner.close();
        filescScanner.close();
        return data;    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileIO file = new FileIO();
        System.out.println(file.getLineScores());
    }
}
```

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7209110/422353

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are calling nextLine():

```
 while((test=filescScanner.nextLine())!=null)
```

it is throwing an [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) to indicate that the scanner has no more lines of input. Thus, it will never return null.

Try instead to use `hasNextLine()` to check if there is a next line.

```
while(filescScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    test=filescScanner.nextline();
    ...
}
```

hasNextLine

**public boolean hasNextLine()**

> Returns: true if and only if this scanner has another line of input ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html))

Therefore, when the scanner do not have any more lines of input to read, `hasNextLine()` will return `false`. Hence, terminating the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you would like the while loop to terminate when where are no more lines left to read in the file.  The Scanner class implements a hasNextLine method which returns true when there is a line to be read and false otherwise.  I think you can replace the while condition with scanner.hasNextLine() and this will address the NoElementException that is being raised at line 41.  I hope you find this answer helpful.

Good Luck
Nikolai