# Meaning of this error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at LineIO.main(LineIO.java:39)
```

There are no lines red out. I'll post code...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class LineIO {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Input file name: ");
        String inputFileName = console.next();
        System.out.print("Output file: ");
        String outputFileName = console.next();
                File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
                Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
                int lineNumber = 1;
                int lineNumber2 = 10;
                int lineNumber3 = 20;
                int lineNumber4 = 30;
                int lineNumber5 = 40;



                System.out.println("Enter name 5 names:");
                String person1 = console.next();
                String person2 = console.next();
                String person3 = console.next();
                String person4 = console.next();
                String person5 = console.next();

                double sum = 0;
                int j = 0;
               while (j < 10)
                {
                  String line = in.nextLine();
                 int num = Integer.parseInt(line);
                  sum = sum+num;
                }
               double average = sum / 10;

            System.out.println(person1 + " average score is " + average);
            System.out.println(person2 + " average score is " + lineNumber2);
            System.out.println(person3 + " average score is " + lineNumber3);
            System.out.println(person4 + " average score is " + lineNumber4);
            System.out.println(person5 + " average score is " + lineNumber5);

                in.close();
                out.close();
    }
}
```

Why do I continue to get this error? I cannot understand the error message and do not understand why the code does not implement. I have my input.txt and output.txt files set up...

Comment: What does "but in code this is not there" mean?

Comment: ^ I fixed this problem.

Comment: which is Line 39? Although I don't think it matters because the error does not seem to come from this code.  i.e. You are not calling `scanner.nextLine`

Comment: My code never came up when copying, line 39 is
         
            "int num = Integer.parseInt(line)" If you could help now that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search came up with this post:  [java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found/7209487#7209487)

You must not have enough lines in the file.

In addition to making sure you have enough lines in your file, also add a check for a next line to avoid this error:

```
            while (j < 10)
            {
              if (in.hasNextLine()){
               String line = in.nextLine();
               int num = Integer.parseInt(line);
               sum += num; //minor change here
              }
              else{
                 System.out.println("Not enough lines!");
                 break;
              }
              j++; //increment j
            }
```

Comment: Thank you. Although it wasn't my only problem it helped show that I was missing a counter as well as off on my initial count (9 instead of 10). Yet I do not understand why the error disappeared when I input your if statement. Probably because I was missing a counter. Either way thank you for taking the time, if it was not for people like you these simple problems for beginners would make a newbie like me not want to code. Thank you.

Comment: @jakecraigslist the check to `hasNextLine()` ensures that you will never get the exception in your question, simply because it prevents reading a line that doesn't exist.  And yes, I can see that your code has other issues as well, but I was just addressing the question about the exception.