# Issue in reading a file with Scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

This is a quite simple task and I have done this a lot of times. But, at the moment, I am stuck at this trivial line of code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

private static Scanner scan;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file = null;
    switch (1) {
    case 1:
        file = new File("W:\\Umesoft Evobus\\From AQUA\\Aqua data_ All\\20090101-20090630_datenabzug_tilde.txt");
        break;
    case 2:
        file = new File("W:\\Umesoft Evobus\\From AQUA\\Aqua data_ All\\20090701-20091231_datenabzug_tilde.txt");
        break;
    }
    scan = new Scanner(file);
    String x = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(x);
  }

}
```

When I try to read the first file, I get a NoSuchElementException. When I try to read the second file, I have no issues. Both the files are from the same source and have the same format. I am sure, there are no issues with regards to the input files. The first line in both the files are identical.

Can someone explain this situation?

The above program is just for testing. Hence, I have used a switch case to select the file.

In the actual program, a set of files are selected by the user. And every time, this file is being skipped. The input files are data files, generated through another program. They are very similar to CSV files, but the delimiter used here is ~ for some reasons. They  cannot be empty, because, even in the worst case, they would have headers.

[Screenshot of the file contents in notepad++:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVDOG.jpg)

Output for file 1:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at controller.Test.main(Test.java:24)
```

Output for file 2:

```
Weltherstellercode~FIN~Fahrzeug_Baumuster~~Motoridentnummer~Getriebe_Identifizierungsnummer~Produktionsdatum~Produktionsnummer_Fzg~Erstzulassungsdatum~Reparaturdatum~Fahrzeug_Laufleistung_in_km~Interne_VEGA_Antragsnummer~TGA~Fehlerort~~Fehlerart~~Reparaturart~~Hauptschadensteil~Reparaturland_(G&K)~~Reparaturbetrieb_(G&K)~~Mitteilungstext~Gutschriftsdatum_(Summe)~Anzahl_Beanstandungen~Gesamtkosten~Lohnkosten~Materialkosten~Summe_DH+NK~Anzahl_Arbeitswerte_(Gutgeschrieben)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have no non-printable characters in the first line?

Comment: JavaDoc says: `@throws NoSuchElementException if no line was found`

Comment: why are u even having a switch case both conditions results in same output

Comment: @npinti Yes. I checked that as well in notepad++

Comment: @Priyamal The switch case is just for testing purpose. 1 to run with the first file. 2 to run with the second. This a snippet for testing. Not the actual program itself.

Comment: @flavio.donze Yes. That, I am aware of. The problem is, the file has contents and still I get this. There is definitely a text in the first line itself. No non printable characters as well.

Comment: also providing a stacktrace would be more helpful

Comment: @Abhishek I have added it now.

Comment: i think the below link might help you out.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/35173548/4626402

Comment: @Abhishek Thank you. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer from a different post, worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35173548/6234625

```
scan = new Scanner(file,"UTF-8");
```

I had to mention the encoding for the Scanner.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me. Thanks especially to @Abhisheik and @Priyamal.

Answer (score 1):

```
       String line ="";
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path"));
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);            
       }
```

i changed previous code to use a buffered reader since

> BufferedReader has significantly larger buffer memory than Scanner.
>   Use BufferedReader if you want to get long strings from a stream, and
>   use Scanner if you want to parse specific type of token from a stream

Comment: This avoids the exception. But, I cannot read the file. I am forcing the program to read the file, because, in my actual program, the file is selected by the user through a GUI. Its a data file and the first line is supposed to contain the headers. Since these are generated from another program, whether or not data is present, the headers are definitely present.

Comment: if it avoids the exception , but at some point is it printing out your line ?

Comment: Please check out the screenshot that I have added. I know this sounds trivially stupid.

Comment: I didn't want to use BufferedReader. It worked with it though. I did find out the solution from another post.