# Java get input until ctrl+z

Tags: java

I have an exercise that gives me x number of inputs and I have to create binary tree with it: https://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/3096
 I have tried this following code

```
Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            String i=inp.next();
            int n=Integer.parseInt(i);
            thetree.addNode(n,"Boss");
        }
```

But when i click `ctrl+z` it gives me errrors like
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at BinaryTree.b1.main(b1.java:41)`

How can I get input until `ctl+z` just like in c++?

Comment: take look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found

Comment: @esprittn thanks it worked!

Comment: Just for the record: in case you found my answer helpful you might still accept it. Thanks for considering...

Comment: @GhostCat sorry but page had too many functions there,so i couldn't  read all of them.

Comment: I am not sure what you are telling me here. The point is: when you want to get into coding, than that will need time. For example: time to study the classes you intend to use. When you are serious about the things you do, then you should be serious about **understanding** the stuff you intend to use. Otherwise, you just walk from one "strange problem" to the next.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use one of the many versions of *hasNext* methods that the scanner provides to you.

See the corresponding [hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) javadoc:

*Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan.*

*next()* just tries to read from the scanner, and if nothing is there (what happens when ctrl-z is pressed), that will fail!