# NoSuchElementException : No line found

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a simple project, I took it from a [website](http://www.hackerearth.com) that gives some challenge to improve my coding skill in java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {        
  public void test() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter something :");
    String str = in.nextLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("you should write something");
    }
    if(str.length()<=30){
        System.out.println("reverse : "+sb.reverse());
    }else {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------");   
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Test1 c = new Test1 ();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {
        System.out.println("case number : " +i);
        c.test();
    }
  }
}
```

> case number : 1 
>   enter something : ayoub 
>   reverse : buoya 
>   ---------------------- 
>   ...loop continue ..

My code works like I want in terminal of eclipse, but when I put it into the "code editor" of the web site, this last one gives me a runtime error that says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
>   at Test1.test(Test1.java:10)
>   at Test1.main(Test1.java:31)

I tried to search on StackOverflow for some solutions but I didn't find it.

Comment: Just guessing, since you don't have quite enough information: eclipse may have connected System.in with the console window so that you can enter things there. I don't know what the '"code editor" of the website' does, but it may be expecting input from some location where you cannot type it. For the future, try to identify what you are working with specifically -- like the name of this 'code editor' you mention -- and since you have a line number in the stack trace, identify the line of code that you posted that matches that line.

Comment: As @arcy mentioned, I think it has to do with the 'code editor'. I tried [this compiler](https://www.compilejava.net/) online and seemed to have the same problem. Whereas, testing the same code worked in Netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using an online java code editor/compiler which does not have an stdin input.

As stated by [arcy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3893496/arcy), you are probably using an IDE with a built-in console window which allows you to pass standard inputs to your program.

The following [online editor](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler) will allow you to add inputs.
You should take care of the way you are using the `nextLine` method of `Scanner`:

The exception you are getting is the result of the scanner not getting any inputs, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found). I suggest you refactor your loop on the scanner using the method `hasNextLine` of [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: @ayoubelmohamedi Happy to help buddy.

Comment: Have been using IntelliJ IDEA's terminal. Project setup has several packages with main methods in it, just to see how things working with multithreading (due to laziness). Used Gradle tasks to run main methods from packages as tasks. Scanner never waited for user input. However if same is done in Main-Class, build and run as jar than works just fine. Sadly took me half a day to solve this. Still don't know why this happening though.