# Why is my java code throwing an error when I get input from the user?

Tags: java, input

I am trying to simply get input from the user, in a method that returns Object. For some reason, this error is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
>   Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found    at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)   at
>   candle.Main.getValue(Main.java:381)   at
>   candle.Main.runFile(Main.java:979)    at
>   candle.Main.main(Main.java:1013)  ... 5 more

Here is a code snippet:

```java
System.out.print("> ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
scanner.close();
```

Can anyone explain how to get this work, or point out something I have done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found): with Scanner you need to check if there is a next line with `hasNextLine()`.  Here is the Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Nothing in that code would explain that exception.  Are you perhaps creating another scanner around system.in and closing it prior to this code?

Comment: I am creating another Scanner object in the main() method, and it is closed using scanner.close(), and it is working fine. Is that why it is calling an error?

Comment: Calling `close()` on a scanner also closes the underlying stream.  If you're closing that other scanner, it will cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: Ah ok I see, how would I get multiple user inputs at different times then?

Comment: You can just reuse the same scanner, or just don't close them when you're done (this will cause a warning, though).

Comment: Ok thanks very much! you have helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before.

1. The basic answer is:

   - Scanner will throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` if there's no line available to read.
   - The solution is:

     ```
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     String input = null;
     if (scanner.hasNextLine()
         scanner.nextLine();
     ```
2. The problem might *also* occur:

   - If you close the scanner prematurely (for example, `input.close()` in some other method)
   - If your input contains special characters, then you should explicitly specify the desired encoding.
     EXAMPLE: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8");`

All of these issues are discussed here:

- [java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found)
- The Javadoc is here:  [class Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)