# Parse Strings in Java

Tags: java

Hey everyone I am new to coding and I want to learn more. I have tried different approches from other codes I have seen relating to this problem. The error that displays is something I have no idea how to fix. Below is my code it keeps giving me an error message.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseStrings {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userInput = "";
      boolean inputDone = false; 

      while (!inputDone) {
         System.out.print("Enter input string: \n");
         userInput = scnr.nextLine();


         if (userInput.equals("q")){
            System.out.println("First word: " + userInput);
            inputDone = true; 
         } else {
            String[] userArray = userInput.split(",");
            System.out.println("First word: " + userArray[0]);
            System.out.println("Second word: " + userArray[1]);
            System.out.println();
        }
      }


      return;
   }
}
```

My inputs are:  Golden , Monkey  Washington,DC  Jill, Allen
Enter input string: q

I am sorry if this is an easy fix.

Comment: This is the error code that popped up. 'Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at ParseStrings.main(ParseStrings.java:11)'

Comment: Please paste the entire stack trace into the question. Not everybody reads the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found)

Comment: Please write exactly your input and output inside \```. Are you typing it by hand or redirecting input?

Answer (score 0):

You're feeding a file or some other limited source into standard in (versus just typing on the console, which is endless, and therefore cannot possibly result in `NoSuchElementException` on the `nextLine()` invocation), and you're passing along, e.g:

```
Golden, Monkey
Washington, DC
Jill, Allen
q
```

**and crucially there is no newline after that q**. nextLine will keep going until it sees a newline, and if end-of-stream arrives first, then there is technically no nextLine to give.

Easy solution: don't use nextline, use `next()` instead, and use `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` to tell scanner that tokens are separated only by newlines (Versus the default, which is any whitespace).

Comment: Or even easier: type a newline after q

Comment: No, @Hawk, that's not the problem. If you're typing on the console, that exception doesn't occur if you fail to hit enter - the program just seems to hang until you do.

Comment: What I meant was ending the redirected input file on an empty line. However, I have just tried the OP's code with your input in a file and it works. Probably OP uses input in a slightly different format.

Answer (score -1):

in your code you are using `String[] userArray = userInput.split(",");` which will split the given string wherever it finds a, but if your entered string which doesn't has a `,` then the array will be empty and when you call it for indexing (`userArray[0]`) it will show an error since no split took place as no `,` was detected.

so there are two solutions:

first: don't use split with `,` use `String[] userArray = userInput.split(" ");` this will split the line based on spaces and hence the String array won't be empty.

second: put the `String[] userArray = userInput.split(",");` in try and catch i.e., if the user doesn't enter a `,` in his input the code won't show an error of empty array also put a suitable code in catch which deals with the `userInput` when the user input doesn't have a `,` in it.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Try it yourself: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Hello".split(",")));` - this prints "Hello". splitting on a thing that isn't in the string returns 1 string in the array (containing all of the input).

Comment: the split function with a `,` is used to split a string of multiple words when there is a `,` in the string but if you want to separate alphabets of a word try `.split("")`  and one more thing don't try doing what you did above in java, it's not python you cant print an array directly, iterate through the elements to print them.