# Issue with the Scanner input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a code to get data from a radiometer sensor connected to one of the "COMs" of the computer, to get the measurement i have to communicate with that sensor throw "COM7" and write the command "gi" to get a value like ""9.919e-08"  for example from the command user interface.

Now i have a problem with the code and it is giving me that error "No line found"

[image]

and here is the code

```
package reading_data;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
    SerialPort sp= SerialPort.getCommPort("COM7");
    sp.setComPortParameters(115200, 8, 1, 0);
    sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

    sp.openPort();
    
    if(sp.isOpen()) {
    System.out.println("Port is open");
        
    PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(sp.getOutputStream());
    Scanner data=new Scanner(sp.getInputStream());
    output.println("gi");
    String ssss=data.nextLine();
    System.out.println("--++++---->"+ssss);
    
    }else {
        System.out.println("Port is not open");
    }   
    
    sp.closePort();

}
}
```

and here is the error i get

```
Port is open
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at reading_data.main.main(main.java:26)
```

May you please tell me where is my mistake?

thanks in advance

Comment: Personally I would call output.flush() after output.println(...) if I want to be sure data is sent. Usually close() should be enough, but if yoou need data before try to flush them when you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found already answered here

Comment: @sigur hello sir, i added that line but still have a problem

Comment: Are you sure the "COMX" has written something? Maybe you're trying to obtain a response before the COM could put the response. There're different ways, the simpliest should be: you put a wait condition in a while !data.hasNextLine and sleep for some milliseconds. Then when data.hasNextLine is true you do the nextLine.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
output.flush();    
if(data.hasNextLine()) {
  String ssss=data.nextLine();
}
```

If no next line, then don't call the nextLine.
Edit.: flush needs to be done.

Comment: hello sir, i did it but the program doesn't enter the if condition, i also tried tp print "data" and the output in the console is like this "java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=true][skipped=false][group separator=\x{2c}][decimal separator=\x{2e}][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]"

Comment: I have modified my comment. As @sigur stated in his comment, you have to flush. Without that, data.hasnext will be always false, because it has no data.