# What does the error " java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found" mean in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have a list called contacts which accepts objects of type contact.
The method i wrote to add a contact to the list always throws the error  "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found", when the method is called more than once in a row.
Apparently the error stems from the line

```
name = scanner.nextLine();
```

I hope someone can point out the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
public void addNewContact() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    int number;
    System.out.print("Enter contact name: ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter contact number: ");
    number = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    Contact contact = new Contact(name, number);
    contacts.add(contact);
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar question with answers. See if it helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do to fix this, is to remove
`scanner.close()`. Instead of using `scanner.close()`, you should put the entire function in `while(true){..}` and use a `break;` to stop it. You also need to change all of the `.nextLine()` to `.next()`. *Do not change the .nextInt()*  This is because `.nextLine()` is more buggy than `.next()`. After fixing these two parts, your code should work properly.

**Final product:**

```
public void addNewContact() {
  while(true){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    int number;
    System.out.print("Enter contact name: ");
    //name = scanner.nextLine(); CHANGED
    name = scanner.next();
    System.out.print("Enter contact number: ");
    number = scanner.nextInt();
    Contact contact = new Contact(name, number);
    contacts.add(contact);
    //scanner.close(); REMOVED
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: '`nextLine()` is more buggy'? Specifics please. What bugs? But if he changes `nextLine()` to `next()` his input prompts won't work properly.

Comment: If you use two .nextLine() for the same scanner, it won't work. I have tested this. He doesn't need to change it.. but if he wants to use two inputs that ask for Strings.. he might need to use .next()