# Can not pass user input in Java constructor

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am tryin to take user input in a parameterized java constructor but I am failing. It gives the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student
{
    String name;
     String date;
    
    Student( String name, String Date)
    {
      this.name=name;
      this.date=date;
    }
    
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Here is the date");
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Enter username");

        String name = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter date");
        String date = myObj.nextLine();
      
        
       Student s1= new Student(name,date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add example input, leading to this exception, to create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently code works fine and issue can't be reproduced.

Comment: As a side note, since ctor parameter is named `Date`, `this.date=date;` does nothing. Either change parameter name do `date`, or change assigning the value to `this.date = Date;`. The first option should be prefered since java variable names start with lower case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found). Search for more.

Comment: From where are you reading input? Which line is line 24 of your program? The stack trace says the exception is thrown there.

Comment: your error is on line `this.date = Date;` you have a parameter named `date`. Variable `Date` basically doesn't exist.

Comment: @m3ow It’s the other way around. The OP has — by mistake, I suppose — named the constructor parameter `Date` with a capital `D`. And no matter which way, this error cannot cause `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/lQXucd)

Comment: @OleV.V. I see what you mean, I had a wrong observation.

Comment: I tried reproducing the error. It might be caused by your input. Say, for example, when I input a ctrl+z on a `nextLine()` it throws NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 1):

According to your stack trace, this has nothing to do with constructors. The error happens when `Scanner` tries to read a line from the standard input.

If you are running this program in IDE, the input via `System.in` might not be available, so there is no next line for `Scanner` to read. Try running your program from console / command line. Some IDEs also have a checkbox for enabling standard input (usually as part of run/debug configuration).