# Trouble with importing files

Tags: java

ZIPCODE, CITY, STATE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE
ZIPCODE, CITY, STATE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE

I'm trying to make this able to open a text file with addresses formatted as such, Create a loop that instantiates a new ZipCode object with the five perameters in order, and then adds that object to ArrayList myZips.

I have a feeling that at least my delimiters are wrong.

```
public void readZipCodeData(String filename){

Scanner inFS = null; 
FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;

try{
    // open the File and set delimiters
    fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
     inFS.useDelimiter(", *");

    // continue while there is more data to read
    while(inFS.hasNext()) {

        // read five data elements
        int zipCode  = inFS.nextInt();
        String city  = inFS.next();
        String state = inFS.next();
        double latitude  = inFS.nextDouble();
        double longitude = inFS.nextDouble();
        ZipCode z1 = new ZipCode(zipCode, city, state, latitude, longitude);
        myZips.add(z1);
    }
    fileByteStream.close();

    // Could not find file
    }catch(FileNotFoundException error1) {
        System.out.println("Failed to read the data file: " + filename);
    // error while reading the file                      
    }catch(IOException error2) {
        System.out.println("Oops! Error related to: " + filename);
}
```

}

Everytime I try running it as is it gives me a
   java.util.InputMismatchException:
   null (in java.util.Scanner) error on the double longitude line.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: woops, it cut that off, just a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `Scanner` for input, but rather `BufferedReader`. I find it simple to use, and I hope this solution works for you:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(filename, charset)) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        // THIS IS THE CODE FOR EVERY LINE
        String[] data = line.split(", ");
        int zipCode = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        String city = data[1];
        String state = data[2];
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(data[4]);
        ZipCode z1 = new ZipCode(zipCode, city, state, latitude, longitude);
        myZips.add(z1);

    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
} catch (NumberFormatException x) {
    System.err.format("NumberFormatException: %s%n", x);
}
```

In this example, I read a whole line with `BufferedReader.readLine()`, and manually parse it using `String.split()` and `Integer.parseInt()` / `Double.parseDouble()`. It's more intuitive, and it works!

See [working example here](http://goo.gl/Gqsi9L).

---

Because of the comment below, I guess I cannot suggest the answer above. However, there are two potential problems I see:

- You might have not put in a `double` in the input file. Simple, honest mistake.
- Or,  by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929135/2397327), your locale may be set wrong. In some places, they use a `,` for decimal point instead of `.` Try switching these around.

Comment: My teacher is very strict on using the code provided to you.  If I used that, even if it was correct, she would go ape shit.  Dunno why

Comment: @David maybe you can look at the example I provided? It might give you ideas. Because you didn't post your whole code, there might be errors elsewhere.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that's wrong is the input -- maybe you didn't input a double?

Comment: I'm glad I helped, but what is the new error / exception now?

Comment: I need to figure out why the try is catching on }catch(FileNotFoundException error1)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Instead of parsing one field at a time, grab the whole line, turn it into an array of `String` using your delimiter `,` then parse to `int`/`double`. `Scanner.nextLine()` grabs the whole line for you.

```
try{
    // open the File and set delimiters
    fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);


        // read five data elements
            String[] data = inFS.nextLine().split(", ");
            int zipCode = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            String city = data[1];
            String state = data[2];
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(data[4]);
        ZipCode z1 = new ZipCode(zipCode, city, state, latitude, longitude);
        myZips.add(z1);
```