# Java Client-Server Double variable passing error

Tags: java, server, double

Code shown below works, if I am trying to pass Integer value from the server back to the client and display the value on screen. Although when I change the value type to Double, it throws error **Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException** in following line in Client class:
result = sc1.nextDouble();

```
class Client {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

   int operation;
   Double amount;
   Double result;

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

   Socket s = new Socket ("127.0.0.1",1234);
   Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (s.getInputStream());


   System.out.println("1.  EUR → GBP");
   System.out.println("2.  EUR → USD");
   System.out.println("3.  EUR → MKD");


   System.out.println("\n");      
   System.out.println("Chose operation :");

   operation = sc.nextInt();


   System.out.println("Amount :");
   amount=sc2.nextDouble();

   PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());

   p.println(amount);
   p.println(operation);

   result = sc1.nextDouble();

   System.out.println(result); 
   }
 }
```

__

```
class Server {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


   int operation;
   Double amount;
   Double result = 1.00;
   ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1234);
   Socket ss =  s1.accept(); 
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());



   amount = sc.nextDouble();
   operation = sc.nextInt();


   if(operation == 1) //EUR-GBP
   {
       result = amount * 0.78;
   }
   if(operation == 2) //EUR-USD
   {
       result = amount*  1.13;
   }
   if(operation == 3) //EUR-MKD
   {
       result = amount* 61.18;
   }



   PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
   p.println(result);
```

}
}

Comment: I have found a solution, its locale dependent. Here is more info:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929120/nextdouble-throws-an-exception-when-i-enter-a-double

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your program and it's working fine for double and integer inputs.

Comment: At the point when I type the value and press enter, it throws an error

Comment: Could you give the exact test case that fails with you ?

Comment: Operation: 1
Amount: 10,56  (Im using netbeans ide).

Comment: Using Netbeans IDE the following is the output
Chose operation :
1
Amount :
10.56
8.2368

Comment: Try To clean the project.
From Run Menu -> Clean and Build 
Then rerun both Server and Client