# Java scanner.nextDouble() gives an exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am learning Java and i have met some problems with scanner.nextDouble and I can`t find any response for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hypotenuse {
public static void main(String[] args){
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type first side: ");
    a = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Type second side: ");
    b = scanner.nextDouble();

    c = Math.sqrt((a*a) + (b*b));
    System.out.println("The c side is: " + c);

    scanner.close();


}
}
```

The problem is when I`m trying to type number with dot like 1.2 for example which is double type. The exception code is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2569)
at Hypotenuse.main(Hypotenuse.java:10)
```

How do I can fix it ? Thanks for help

Comment: Hi! (Try) Type with comma! (Depends on your system locale/the "shell" you use.)

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to change typing from comma to dot?

Comment: Hello, Please try to find an answer before you ask a question, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929120/nextdouble-throws-an-inputmismatchexception-when-i-enter-a-double) is the same question with possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your system. But if you really want to use the dot, you can change the `Locale` to make a `Scanner` read dots in this way:

```
new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

**For example:**

- `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Local.US);` will
  use the dot
- `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Local.ITALY);` will use the comma.